# How to rescaling the intensity values in the original image to cover the entire dynamic range

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a program for segmentation of lesion. In part of my program I want rescaling the intensity values in the original image to cover the entire dynamic range.
my code:

```
cvtColor(src, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

Mat kernel = Mat::ones(5, 5, CV_32F)/21;
kernel.row(0).col(0) = 0;
kernel.row(0).col(4) = 0;
kernel.row(4).col(0) = 0;
kernel.row(4).col(4) = 0;

//circular averaging low pass filter with a radius of 5, using the pill-box point spread function
filter2D(gray, gray, -1, kernel, Point(-1,-1));


threshold(gray, dst, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
```

I am looking for solution for to do. It should Before threshold Done.

Comment: Not sure if it is this what you want but I often use: pixel = 255*(float)(pixel - min)/(float)(max-min) with min and max the minimum and maximum intensities in the whole image.

Comment: Namely for each pixel I use the "pixel = 255*(float)(pixel - min)/(float)(max-min)"